# Android: How can I convert the WSDL file in something understable by Android

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, android-ksoap2

I have a litle problem:

I have a WSDL file and i would like to use it on android developpement.
For exemple, for the iPhone, I found this website: http://sudzc.com/ which converts the WSDL in a code suitable for iOS but how can I do this on Android. I readed something abaut ksoap2...

Thank you.

Comment: I have found the solution, you can use the Axis2 wsdl2java.

Comment: Hi Milos. You should post your solution as an answer, and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, you can use the wsclient.neurospeech.com. this is a shareware but you have a demo version which will do 99% of the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this [Android web Service client generation tool](http://code.google.com/p/android-ws-client/)

It uses [cxf wsdl2java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) in background to generate the java client stub for android platform for you. you have to just put the sources and some library in your project. and you can just call it in some "method call fashion" just we do in our enterprise project, you don't need to know the namespace/soap action etc. And its fully open and free.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try www.wsdl2code.com it solved most of my problems :)

```
SampleService srv1 = new SampleService();
     req = new Request();                     
     req.companyId = "1";
     req.userName = "userName";                                     
     req.password = "pas";
     Response response =    srv1.ServiceSample(req);
```